# Using Ionic Material with Ionic and Cordova 5

Tags: angularjs, ionic-material

I'm trying to run the demo in Mac Yosemite with Ionic and Cordova 5. At Ionic-Material/demo running bower install ionic-material causes an 
`Failed to execute "git ls-remote --tags --heads https://github.com/fians/Ink.git", exit code of #128 remote: Repository not found. fatal: repository 'https://github.com/fians/Ink.git/'`  to appear.

As in https://github.com/zachsoft/Ionic-Material/issues/18 I tried removing the Ionic-Material folder present originally in the demo, then it loaded without an error on bower install but on running 'ionic serve' it still showed a white screen. I even tried copying the original demo files of the lib/Ionic-Material ( the json, css and js files) into the new installed lib/Ionic-Material folder, yet it showed a white screen. Can anyone please solve the error or put up detailed instructions for it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code in the demo of the plugin was not updated to the latest version of ionic-material.  I Put up a pull request after updating the code. Please comment if anyone else finds an error to my pull